# Segmentation and Classification in ERDAS

Tags: raster, erdas-imagine

I have segmented an image inn erdas and will want to use it in a classification exercise, how do i proceed?

My image is a low resolution 30m alos.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure what exactly you mean by 'segmented' but if you want to classify an image in ERDAS, you can go directly to menu Classification.

You can choose whether to use Supervised Classification or Unsupervised Classification.

If you have a training sample or ground checking area, that would better to guide you to precise result of classification.

Comment: Ya you are right but i read that segmentation can also be used to improve  classification, how that is done is the issue. So far the results i am getting for both the supervised and unsupervised classification is not good, a lot of errors and miss classification. i am looking for a means to improve. Thanks anyway